# Dot.NET Core Routing and Controller Processing discrepancy

Tags: asp.net-core, url-routing

I am trying to use the asp-route- to build a query string that I am using to query the database.
I am confused on how the asp-route- works because I do not know how to specifically use the route that I created in my cshtml page.  For example:

If I use the old school href parameter approach, I can then, inside my controller, use the specified Query to get the parameter and query my database, like this:

If I use this href:

```
<a href="/Report/Client/?ID=@ulsin.ID">@ulsin.custName</a>
```

then, in the controller, I can use this:

```
HttpContext.Request.Query["ID"]
```

The above approach works and I am able to work with the parameter.  However, if I use the htmlHelper approach, such as:

```
<a asp-controller="Report" asp-action="Client" asp-route-id="@ulsin.ID">@ulsin.custName</a>
```

How do I get that ID from the Controller?  The href approach does not seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Anchor Tag Helper documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asp-route-value), if the requested route parameter (`id` in your case) is not found in the route, it is added as a query parameter. Therefore, the following final link will be generated: `/Report/Client?id=something`. Notice that the query parameter is lowercase.

When you now try to access it in the controller as `HttpContext.Request.Query["ID"]`, since `HttpContext.Request.Query` is a collection, indexing it would be case-sensitive, and so "ID" will not get you the query parameter "id". Instead of trying to resolve this manually, you can use a feature of the framework known as [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which will allow you to automatically and case-insensitively get the value of a query parameter.

Here is an example controller action that uses model binding to get the value of the query parameter `id`:

```cs
// When you add the id parameter, the framework's model binding feature will automatically populate it with the value of the query parameter 'id'.
// You can then use this parameter inside the method.
public IActionResult Client(int id)
```